# erro no envio de dados via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Não estou conseguindo enviar os dados para o mysql via ajax , não sei em que parte de meu código poderia está errado.
Meu index que na qual as categorias são listado do banco de dados via jquery.

```
<div class="container">

           <h1 class="restaurant-title">Peixaria</h1>


          <div id="menu-panel" class="col-sm-12 paddingselect">

                  <?php
                     categoriaas();
                  ?>

          </div>


          <div id="menu-panel-2">




          </div>



          <div id="caja-panel">
            <div class="well">


                <!-- left -->
                <div id="theproducts" class="col-sm-5">
                </div>
                <!-- left -->
                <form method="post" action="relatorio.php">
                <input type="text" id="theinputsum">

                <!-- right -->
                <div id="thetotal" class="col-sm-7">
                   <h1 id="total"></h1>
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Finalizar Pedido</button>
                </form>
                </div>
                <!-- right -->


            </div>
          </div>



     </div>
```

o código ajax da qual estou querendo enviar para o mysql.

```
<script>
$('#theinputsum').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formDados = new FormData($(this)[0]);
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "relatorio.php",
  data: $("#theinputsum").serialize()
})
  .done(function( retorno) {
    alert( "muito bem" );
});
};
 </script>
```

e o código que na qual envia e lista para o mysql

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');


//Criar a conexao
$link = new mysqli ("localhost", "root", "", "restaurant");
if($link->connect_errno){
     echo"Nossas falhas local experiência ..";
     exit();
}
$pedido = $_POST['products'];
$preco = $_POST['products'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO `pedido` (`pedido`,`preco`) VALUES ('{$pedido}','{$preco}')";

$link->query($sql);



         $sql= "SELECT id_pedido,numero_mesa,pedido_refeicao,num_refeicao,pedido_bebida,num_bebida,data FROM mpedido ORDER BY id_pedido DESC LIMIT 1";
        $consulta = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

?>
```

Comment: Qual está sendo o erro?

Comment: De novo? Você irá insistir em ficar recriando tópicos com a mesma pergunta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu código tem alguns problemas:
Você esta usando o evento "submit" no componente errado.
Troque esta linha

```
<form method="post" action="relatorio.php">
```

Por esta

```
<form method="post" action="relatorio.php" id="formRel">
```

e esta

```
$('#theinputsum').submit(function(event){
```

por esta

```
$('#formRel').submit(function(event){
```

e esta

```
data: $("#theinputsum").serialize()
```

por esta

```
data: $("#formRel").serialize()
```

Você já começa a enviar o dados para o php. No arquivo php não há retorno nenhum se tudo focar ok, se você quiser retornar algo ao html , uma boa prática é escolher um tipo de retorno na sua requisição ajax assim:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "relatorio.php",
  data: $("#formRel").serialize(),
  dataType : "html"
})
```

No .done você retorna o conteúdo da página php em alguma div por exemplo:

```
.done(function( retorno) {
    alert( "muito bem" );
    $("#idDaDiv").html(retorno);
});
```

Por fim seu arquivo php deve imprimir (pode ser com echo mesmo), o resultado que vc quer que apareça na div.

Mais informações nos links http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ e http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: @RodrigoSartoriJabouche Obrigado . mas eu só quero mesmo é enviar para o mysql e depois faço em uma outra pagina para listar . Muito Obrigado

Comment: Ok, faça até a parte que envia então...

Comment: e a parte que inserir no mysql , poderia ficar igual como está ?

Comment: Pode, só não irá ter um retorno se deu certo ou errada a inserção.. para tanto se vc fizer tudo o que eu falei, você terá a resposta "Nossas falhas local experiência .."

Comment: olá passei a noite toda e não conseguir enviar nada para o mysql da maneira que você falou

Comment: Desenvolvimento as vezes é meio complicado, eu sugiro que você comece tentando coisas mais simples e vá avançando, dá uma olhada nesse tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp.

Comment: Reparou nesta linha? $preco = $_POST['products']; Veja o tipo de dado do campo preço na tabela. tente dar um echo na sua query, você tem que debugar...

Comment: Pois é eu dei um echo e a o array parece vazio .

Comment: Olhe as propriedade name dos seus inputs, elas são iguais aos que vc busca no $_POST? Aconselho que você dê uma boa olha em conceitos básicos

Comment: bem , só um input que tem name"" o outro é o que vem via ajax do mysql, tipo a tela de categorias vem via javascript ai só tem essa linha  <input type="text" id="theinputsum"> que faz isso . Como poderia fazer para colocar ela no post ?

Comment: Você criar os inputs...

Comment: Mas como poderia fazer outros inputs se os produtos são dinâmicos , feitos em jquery e via ajax do mysql , e quando clico no pedido ele é selecionado como mostra a figura .Posso lhe mandar o sistema todo por email .

Comment: Cara ai sua pergunta não tem como ser respondida ela tem mais de contexto, tente algo mais simples e vá avançando